# Ursprung von "Verunglimpfen"

Tags: etymology

*Verunglimpfen* ist ein seltsames Wort in dem Sinne, dass mir als Muttersprachler die Wurzel fremd ist.

*verun-* ist ja eine Vorsilbe, die etwas negiert - aber was ist *-glimpfen*? Und wo kommt der Ausdruck her?

Comment: Zuwenig für eine Antwort: Es gibt _glimpflich_, und [DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=verunglimpfen&view=1) schreibt was dazu.

Comment: 'Glimpflich' davonkommen mag verwandt sein, aber welcher Glimpf stand hier Pate? `Der Glimpf und der Glumpf, versackten im Sumpf, der Glumpf und der Glimpf, bekamen dann Schimpf`. unbekannter Dichter

Comment: Richtig viel gibts noch bei [Grimm](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?bookref=8,103,18)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Das Wort hat dieselbe Wurzel wie *glimpflich*, das aus dem mittelhochdeutschen *gelimpflich* (Althochdeutsch: galimpflich, galimpflīh) mit der Hauptbedeutung *anständig, angemessen* entstanden ist.

Der [Wikipedia-Artikel zum Substantiv *Verunglimpfung*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verunglimpfung) zur Herkunft des Wortes:

> Das Wort ist als Gegenbegriff abgeleitet von dem fast untergegangenen Wort **Glimpf** („Schonung, Nachsicht“; von ahd. gilimpf „gelegen sein“, später „Angemessenheit“, „Billigkeit“ vgl. Unbill) . Jemanden „glimpflich zu behandeln“ bedeutet demgemäß, ihn wohlwollend behandeln; wenn etwas „glimpflich abläuft“, verursacht es keine schlechten Folgen.
>
> Unglimpf steht in schwankendem Geschlecht ags. ungelimp, n., m., ahd. ungelimfe, f. n., mhd. ungelimpf, ungelimp, ungelump, m., frühnhd. auch wieder f. als ung(e)limpf(f) in der Bedeutung „Mangel an Nachsicht und Rücksicht; Ungunst; Unliebenswürdigkeit; Ernst“. Es findet sich auch norw. ulempa, dän. ulempe, schwed. olämplighet entlehnt.

Comment: Sind die entsprechenden Wörter in den skandinavischen Sprachen wirklich *entlehnt* oder stammen sie nicht viel eher aus derselben Wurzel?

Comment: Das schwedische Wort "olämplig" bedeutet unpassend, ungeeignet.